# Is the selectedBackGroundView shown above or below contentView in UICollectionViewCells?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, selected

I've been looking around online trying to find out what the view hierarchy of the `UICollectionViewCell` is.

I know it has a `contentView` a `selectedBackgroundView` and `backgroundView`.
From what I understand the `backgroundView` is at the very back. But is the `selectedBackgroundView` behind or in front of the `contentView` in the case of a `UICollectionViewCell`.

Also is the order for this view hierarchy the same for a `UITableViewCell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `selectedBackgroundView` is behind the `contentView`. From the Apple documentation:

> When the cell is selected, this view is layered above the
>   backgroundView and behind the contentView.

Comment: Thank you! and does the internal implemenation take care of adding the `selectedbackgroundview` to `UICollectionCellView`'s hierarchy? Or do you need to add it yourself? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I believe iOS takes care of that since you simply have to set the properties for the cell.

Also, if the answer was helpful, can you please mark it as "correct"?

Answer (score 1):

Apple documentation says that "**cell manages two background views that display the cell in its selected and unselected states.**" So `backGroundView` and `selectedbackgroundView` both are behind the content view. The `selectedbackgroundView` is displayed just above the background view when the cell is selected. Source https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewcell